# Intermittent server error in iOS7

Tags: ios7, network-programming, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using NSURLSessionDownloadTask to pull down a simple text file from my goDaddy server using the following code:

```
-(void)getTheInternetFile
//Fire up the downloadTask to pull the file down from my web server.
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getTheFile = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/utility/file.txt"]] 
completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) 
{
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't do what I want as we have an error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"It worked");
    }
    }];

    [getTheInternetFile resume];
}
```

The problem I am having is that this works really well...sometimes.  Other times I get an error message that states:  "A server with the specified hostname could not be found".

As the URL is hard coded and never changes, I am at a loss to how this can even happen.  Unless goDaddy is letting me down, and the server has all of a sudden become unavailable part of the time, I am at a loss.  For what it's worth this just started acting this way today, so maybe it is goDaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was goDaddy's server having issues, despite their website reporting that there were none.  It took 15 minutes on hold to find out that my code is fine.